# Transforming Kusto array into specific tabular format

Tags: sankey-diagram, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have my data in the format

[image]

I need to transform the data into 
[source, destination and count] format

[image]

so that I can create a sankey chart out of it. Can I do any transform like this in Kusto itself or is this possible only via a programming language? If it can be done in kusto itself, can you point the way please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transforming a dynamic array is possible using [mv-apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator) operator, then you could use [prev()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/prevfunction) function to get the previous row's value in order to generate the *From* column:

```
datatable (IdCol:long, Ordered_States_List:dynamic )
[1,dynamic(["State01","State02","State05"]),
2,dynamic(["State02","State03","State05"]),
3,dynamic(["State01","State04"]),
4,dynamic(["State01","State02","State03"])]
| mv-apply Ordered_States_List to typeof(string) on 
(
    project From = prev(Ordered_States_List), To=Ordered_States_List
)
| where isnotempty(From)
| summarize value=count() by From, To
```